# Having difficulty in getting previous query record

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have 4 store at different levels. (Store A, Store B, Store C, Store D). The stores keep the items. (Item1, Item2, Item3, Item4 and Item5).

I have 3 tables (Item Table, Store Table, 
[Tracking Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Swl3N.png)) and 1 query (
[Store_rec query for Item2 in Store B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6xwP.png)).

Tracking table has columns (ID, T_Date, Item_ID, Item_Name, Store_From, Store_To, Amount, Remark).

Store_rec query table is to check the changes of an Item in a Store (in my case - Item 2 in Store B). It has 5 columns (SrNo, T_Date, Location_To/From (From B to others/ From others to B), Received (B balance increase) and Dispatched (B balance decrease).

My problems are:

1. I can't sort SrNo in ascending order without affecting the row number of T_Date.
2. I want to add a balance column in Store_rec query as shown in the picture. (Balance = Previous balance + Received - Dispatched).

I searched in Google, read in forums, tutorials and examples but still can't solve my problem.

Please help.

```
SELECT (
        SELECT COUNT(aa.[ID]) + 1
        FROM Tracking AS aa
        WHERE (
                t.[Store_From] = "Store B"
                OR t.[Store_To] = "Store B"
                )
            AND aa.[ID] < t.[ID]
        ) AS SrNo
    ,t.T_Date
    ,IIf(t.[Store_To] = "Store B", t.[Store_From], t.[Store_To]) AS [Location_To/From]
    ,IIf(t.[Store_To] = "Store B", t.[Amount], 0) AS Received
    ,IIf(t.[Store_From] = "Store B", t.[Amount], 0) AS Dispatched
FROM Tracking AS t
WHERE (
        t.[Store_From] = "Store B"
        OR t.[Store_To] = "Store B"
        )
    AND t.[Item_Name] = "Item 2"
ORDER BY t.[T_Date];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select  T1.id ,IIF(Store_From = 'Store B',Store_To, Store_From) ,IIF(Store_To = 'Store B',0, Amount) AS Dispatched, IIF(Store_From = 'Store B',0, Amount) AS Received,SUM(T.Received) AS RemainingBal
  From track  as T1

left join (

select  id,(-IIF(Store_To = 'Store B',0, Amount) + IIF(Store_From = 'Store B',0, Amount) ) AS Received
  From track 

) as  T ON T.id <= T1.id

WHERE   Item_Id = 'Item_2'
        AND ( Store_From = 'Store B'
              OR Store_To = 'Store B'
            )

GROUP BY 
        T1.Store_From ,
        T1.Store_To,T1.id,Amount
        ORDER BY T1.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  id ,
        CASE WHEN Store_From = 'Store B' THEN Store_To
             ELSE Store_From
        END AS Location_To ,
        CASE WHEN Store_To = 'Store B' THEN 0
             ELSE Amount
        END AS Dispatched ,
        CASE WHEN Store_From = 'Store B' THEN 0
             ELSE Amount


        END AS Received
INTO    #Tmp
FROM    dbo.Tracking
WHERE   Item_Id = 'Item_2'
        AND ( Store_From = 'Store B'
              OR Store_To = 'Store B'
            )

SELECT  T1.Location_To ,       
        T1.Received ,T1.Dispatched ,
        SUM(T.Dispatched) AS RemainingBal
FROM    #Tmp AS T1
        LEFT JOIN ( SELECT  ISNULL(( -CAST(Dispatched AS INT) + CAST(Received AS INT) ),
                                   0) AS Dispatched ,
                            id
                    FROM    #Tmp
                  ) AS T ON T.id <= T1.id
GROUP BY T1.Location_To ,
        T1.Dispatched ,
        T1.Received
```

Comment: I got error message "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'CASE WHEN Store_From = 'Store B' THEN Store_To ELSE Store_From END AS Location_To'".
So I tried vba code. Creating Tmp query is OK. But I got error msg in vba code to create 'Store_rec query'. Error in `"SELECT  T1.Location_To, T1.Received ,T1.Dispatched , SUM(T.Dispatched) As RemainingBal FROM Tmp AS T1 LEFT JOIN ( SELECT  ISNULL(( -CAST(Dispatched AS INT) + CAST(Received AS INT) ), 0) AS Dispatched , id FROM Tmp) AS T ON T.id <= T1.id GROUP BY T1.Location_To ,T1.Dispatched ,T1.Received"`

Answer (score 0):

Thank your for helping me. I edited some points in the provided codes above. The code is as follow

```
SELECT T1.TDate,IIF(T1.Store_From = 'Store B',T1.Store_To, T1.Store_From) AS Location, IIF(T1.Store_From = 'Store B',0, T1.Amount) AS Received, IIF(T1.Store_To = 'Store B',0, T1.Amount) AS Dispatched, SUM(T.Received) AS Balance FROM Tracking AS T1 LEFT JOIN (SELECT aa.id, aa.TDate, (-IIF(aa.Store_To = 'Store B',0, aa.Amount) + IIF(aa.Store_From = 'Store B',0, aa.Amount) ) AS Received FROM Tracking AS aa WHERE aa.Item_Name = 'Item 2')  AS T ON T.id <= T1.id WHERE Item_Name = 'Item 2' AND (Store_From = 'Store B' OR Store_To = 'Store B') GROUP BY T1.TDate,T1.Store_From, T1.Store_To, T1.id, Amount ORDER BY T1.TDate;
```